# Non alternative $k$-linear maps vanishing on $\sum x_i=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Assume that $V$ is a finite dimensional real vector space of dimension $n$.
Is there a $\mathbb{R} -$ valued $k$- linear map $T$ on $V$ which is not an alternative form but it vanish on all $k$- tuple $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k)$ with $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i =0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.** Notice that by linearity we should have
$$
  f(v_1,\dots,v_{k-1},\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_{k-1}v_{k-1})
  =\frac{f(\alpha_1v_1,\dots,\alpha_{k-1}v_{k-1},-\alpha_1v_1-\dots-\alpha_{k-1}v_{k-1})}{(-1)^k\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_{k-1}}
  =0
$$
for all nonzero $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{k-1}$. Since each linear combination is a sum of two linear combinations with nonzero coefficients, this also holds for all $\alpha_i$ [this argument works also for all fields with at least 3 elements]. Thus, the linear map $f$ vanishes on all linearly dependent $k$-tuples, in which case it is well known to be alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How does this argument work for a triple $f(v,v,w)$, for example?

Comment: You may perform the same for the last two vectors instead of the first two.

Comment: Yes but you implicitly assume that all  $\alpha_i$ are non zero. i can imagine  a resolution for three vector: $2f(v,v,w)=f(v,v.2w+2v)+f(v,v,-2v)=0$. I guess that the general case can be solved, similarly. Yes?

Comment: No, I _first_ explicitly tell that all $\alpha_i$ are nonzero, and _second_ tell that by summing two such expression we can get an _arbitrary_ linear combination, with each coefficient being zero or nonzero on our choice.

Comment: My apology if my question is elementary: but may you apply your  statement "Since each linear  combination is a sum of two linear combinations with non zero coefficients" to the triple $(v,v,w)$?

Comment: $f(v,v,w)=f(1\cdot v+0\cdot w,v,w)=f(2v+w,v,w)-f(v+w,v,w)=0$.